# How to format BigDecimal property of Struts2 iterator variable using getText()

Tags: jsp, struts2, el, ognl

I am having an issue with formatting a `BigDecimal` in `Struts2` using the `<s:property>` tag together with `getText()`.
The first time I use it (before the iterator tag), it works as expected.
The second time I try to use it, it is with a property of the iterator variable. In this case it doesn't print anything.
I have `Struts2` with `devMod` *on*, and I don't get any Exceptions either. 
However, the same property, when outputted using the `<s:property>` tag without `getText()` works as expected.

I have tried all sorts of alternatives like enclosing the variable in `%{}`, removing the enclosing alltogether,
adding the name of the variable with a `hash tag`, and more variants.

There is an answer for using the `<s:text>` tag, but even if this is an alternative, I would like to know how to get this working with `getText`.

**The class for the "reporte" object made available to the JSP with getter and setter in the Action.**

```
public class Reporte {

    List<Reporte.Item> detalle = new ArrayList<>();
    BigDecimal totalGeneral;

    public List<Reporte.Item> getDetalle() {
        return detalle;
    }

    public void setDetalle(List<Reporte.Item> detalle) {
        this.detalle = detalle;
    }

    public void setTotalGeneral(BigDecimal totalGeneral){
        this.totalGeneral = totalGeneral;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalGeneral(){
        return this.totalGeneral;
    }


    public static class Item{ 
        private BigDecimal total;

        public BigDecimal getTotal() {
            return total;
        }
        public void setTotal(BigDecimal total) {
            this.total = total;
        }   
    }
}
```

**The JSP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Reporte</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{reporte.totalGeneral})"/> <br/>  <%-- works --%>

    <s:iterator var="det" value="reporte.detalle">
        <s:property value="total"/> <%-- works --%>
        <s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}', {total})"/><br/> <%-- doesn't print anything --%>
    </s:iterator>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the iteration variable `det.total`

Comment: @jspcal To my understanding I am doing that. I also tried with {#det.total}. Update: {det.total} didn't work either.

Comment: You shouldn't need curly braces around the parameter names; I'm not even sure why it works. Since `det` will be on the stack you shouldn't need `det.total`, just `total` should work. Actually you shouldn't need to set a `var`, it's just how to name what gets pushed onto the stack. The first arg to `getText` should be the property key of the format string--maybe you can pass in an immediate format now, I haven't been keeping up, not sure why that works for `reporte.totalGeneral`. I'll have to set up a quick test app to check.

Comment: @DaveNewton I managed to resolve my  problem what I think is the answer by referencing the action while inside the loop.

Comment: @jspcal I manged to resolve the problem by referencing the action inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding `#action.` before `getText` when it is called inside the iterator tag.

My understanding is that `getText()` is a member function of the `Action` (`SupportAction`) so when the action is at the top of the stack it can be called without specifying the variable.

```
<s:property value="#action.getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}', {total})"/><br/>
```

Inside the iterator, the item is put on the top of the stack, so to call the `getText` of the action the variable name needs to be referenced.

**Tip:** What really hepled me to figure this out were the use of the `<s:degub>` tag, and while using `devMod`, the `?debug=xml` parameter following the action to get a dump of the stack (which requires IE).